# Pod library not updated

Tags: git, cocoapods, podspec

I am the owner of a pod library "[HDTableDataSource](https://github.com/HarshitDaftary/HDTableDataSource)". When I released initial version, it had a bug in code. So I fixed the bug and updated my pod library but it does not update the code.

I fixed the issue in my git push of tag 2.4 and then updated the  [pod spec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/HDTableDataSource/2.5/HDTableDataSource.podspec.json) file to refer the tag 2.4. But it still gets the code of older version. I tried agin with tag 2.5 to 2.7 but still it refers to the old code of tag 2.3 of git.

Kindly help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After pushing your tag to your repo, have your pushes to cocoapods been successful?

`pod trunk push NAME.podspec`

Adding `--verbose` can help troubleshoot problems if the push is failing.

source: https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html#release